# handling multiple Domains for Active Directory Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, active-directory-group

In my application I have the following method which I pass the AD Username to it (example: Domain1\User1) and try to find the groups that user belongs to in Active Directory.

```
     public ActionResult Login(string userName)
   {
        PrincipalContext up = new   PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        UserPrincipal users = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(up,IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = users.GetGroups();
        IEnumerable<string> userGroupList = groups.Select(p =>p.SamAccountName);
        return userGroupList ;
    }
```

The code works perfectly, However I am guessing this code will failto work in an environment where there are multiple domains.
For example:
1) User try to login with (**Domain1\User1**) and it will go through,
2) User try to login with (**Domain2\User2**) the app will try to look for **User2** in **Domain1**, and becasue there is no such user in Domain1 it will fail.

Is this true? if yes, how can I resolve this issue so it will works with multiple domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to pass the Domain name as the second parameter when trying to instantiate new PrincipalContext object.
By doing this I was able to retrieve user groups with multiple domains. 
So the code will be something like this :

```
      PrincipalContext up = new   PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"DomainName");
```